# GetModuleHandle on Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, static-linking

I am trying to load the winsock dll on Windows Phone 8.0 native C++ library.

```
 HMODULE ws2mod = GetModuleHandle("ws2_32.dll");
    win_getaddrinfo = GetProcAddress(ws2mod, "getaddrinfo");
    if (win_getaddrinfo)
        return win_getaddrinfo(node, service, hints, res);
```

I am getting a linker error:

```
Error   178 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol GetModuleHandle referenced in
```

When I double click and do Goto Definition on Visual Studio, I see the definition in libloaderapi.h file within Windows Phone Kits.

What is the library that I should link with? Here are the current libraries:

```
WindowsPhoneCore.lib
RuntimeObject.lib
PhoneAppModelHost.lib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetModuleHandle` is not on the list of approved APIs for WP8.

However `getaddrinfo` is.  I think you can just link to `ws2_32.lib` and call `getaddrinfo` directly, rather than via `GetProcAddress`.